# the meaning of "how long do you think they will be"

Tags: phrase-meaning

i can't understand the meaning for this question "how long do you think they **'will be'**"

is the meaning talk about how long"they" will arrive in the place ?

Comment: We need much more context. It could mean any number of things. (1) How long before they arrive? (2) How long before they can accomplish something? (3) When will they no longer be busy?  If they are cooking pasta noodles or cutting lumber it could be asking (4) What length do you think they will be?

Comment: Welcome! English is a context-dependent language, as indicated by Jason Bassford. As well as answering Jason's questions, I suggest you include more of the conversation that led up to the phrase you are asking about.

Comment: This question refers to the amount of time it will take some people (_they_) to do something they are currently engaged in. The speaker is asking the addressee (who is not one of the people being asked about) how long that task will take for those people. _How long will they be doing that/gone to the store/up in the attic?_

Comment: Me:  I ordered some hoses online.  She:  How long do you think they will be?  Me:  About 10 feet each.

Comment: @Hot Licks -  Alternatively ---  Me: I ordered some hoses online. She: How long do you think they will be? Me: About 10 weeks judging by *how long* the last order took to arrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

How long do you think they 'will be'  or; How much time will they spend there?

As with many sentences spoken, or quoted as spoken, this is a normal shortening of the fuller sentence. If They had gone to the movies the question would be; "How long do you think they 'will be' *at the movies?*"

It would work just as well as: "How long do you think they 'will be' *at the cricket match?*"

In each case the *length* is that of time and the *being* is that of the people at a location or event.

Comment: It could be heard among a group of people waiting for other people to finish a meeting.